# Multiple WHERE conditions on the same table columns

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql, doctrine-query

I am trying to get parts which have certain attributes. Each `part` has many attributes, and each `attribute` has an `attributeheader`. So there's three tables that I need to use.

```
SELECT * FROM Part p 
LEFT JOIN p.attributes pa
JOIN pa.attributeheader pah
WHERE (sph.name = 'size' AND sp.value IN ('11')) 
AND (sph.name = 'colour' AND sp.value IN ('Black'))
```

This returns nothing as I've gone wrong somewhere on the JOIN, or the lack of grouping. I'm trying to select the parts which have both attributes, so using `OR` is not a solution. I can't quite work out how to go about this - using raw MySQL I would use aliases on the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE (sph.name = 'size' AND sp.value IN ('11'))
AND (sph.name = 'colour' AND sp.value IN ('Black'))
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE sph.name = 'size' AND sp.value IN ('11') 
AND sph.name = 'colour' AND sp.value IN ('Black')
```

and of course sph.name cannot be equal to both 'size' and 'colour' at the same time, therefore you won't ever get any row from this SELECT.

You need to join attributes table twice.

More or less this way:

```
SELECT * FROM (Part p 
LEFT JOIN p.attributes pa
JOIN pa.attributeheader pah)
LEFT JOIN p.attributes pa2
JOIN pa.attributeheader pah2
```

And you will need to prefix values in the WHERE clause with pa. or pa2. and so on.

And maybe you shouldn't execute such queries in a relational database but rather in a datawarehouse or an indexed search engine supporting faceting.

Comment: I was not aware Doctrine could use multiple aliases in this way, I will give this a go.

Comment: I don't speak DQL (hence "more or less this way") but it works using SQL therefore Doctrine is likely to provide such feature.

Comment: The doc (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder) shows an "alias" parameter for join() and leftJoin() functions, so this should be right.